# Should a file header be a class or a struct?

Tags: c#, class, struct, file-format

I'm parsing a file format with a header.
(Note: I don't write any files, I only read and parse)

Because it won't be changed, its header can be passed by value.
So I would guess a struct would be the best choice but I'm not sure because I almost never use them.

Is there any reason why I should (not) make it a class or a struct?

Edit: It's hard to provide an example at the moment.
You can compare it to any basic file header.
It includes the signature ('magic number'), the version and the 'sub-type'.

Comment: It matters if there are strings or variable-length fields in the header. It should not be hard to make up a sample header, in C# or as a field-layout.

Comment: There are no strings and no variable-length fields in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "won't be changed" part is an indicator for immutable, not for value-type.

You probably want a class, but it's impossible to be sure without an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) then I suggest class.

Comment: I guess you're talking about deserialization and even then, the answer is no.